# how can I load from room database data to autofill a form?

Tags: java, android

first of all I'm very new in Android Studio and I'm trying to figure it out so please, be patient with me.
The thing is I'm working with ROOM and I have an XML form asociated to my activity and I want it to autocomplete the fields of the form based on the result of a query. The field that's used for the query is one filled by the user.
How can I do that? Because I've been searching but didn't succeed. Any help here will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The Query in the Dao

```
@Query("Select * from Animal where caravana = :caravana")
Animal findByCaravana(int caravana);
@Insert
void insert(Animal animal);
```

The code in my activity:

```
private EditText editTextCaravana;
private Spinner spinnerRaza;
private Spinner spinnerCategoria;

public void Save{
  animal = new Animal();
  animal.setCaravana(Integer.parseInt(editTextCaravana.getText().toString()));
  animal.setCategoria(spinnerCategoria.getSelectedItem().toString());
  animal.setRaza(spinnerRaza.getSelectedItem().toString());
  animalRepository.update(animal);
  
}
```

The thing is I need to write the autofill function

```
public void searchAndAutofill{
  animal = animalRepository.findByCaravana(Integer.parseInt(editTextCaravana.getText().toString())); //this assignment doesn't work
 //and here goes the code to autofill the form. I've no idea how to do it
 //please help!!!
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Writing to the database, reading from it, filling your form once you've read the data?

Comment: reading from it and filling the form. I've tried animal = findBycaravana( <int parser>). findByCaravana is the function that does the query

Comment: Well without seeing any code it's impossible to know what you need help with I'm afraid. There is great official documentation on writing and reading data with Room. Then a basic Android tutorial should give you the rest. Good luck!

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my question tomorrow to show the code to see how can I be helped.

Comment: Do you get an error reading from DB or any other stage? Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: The error is that animal=animalRepository.findByCaravana(Integer.parseInt(editTextCaravana.getText().toString())); It says Required type Animal, provided void.

Comment: @Jenifer Check your _findByCaravana()_ method in _AnimalRepository_ its return type should be "Animal" not "void".

Comment: I've tried to do that but didn't work. It gives me an error. I will put the error in this thread.